# Apply code highlighter to Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea in my website contains PHP code.

I want to make the users able to Modify the code and then Run it.

So, I have made a textarea called `modifyCode`:

```
 <textarea id="modifyCode"></textarea>
```

So far I have managed to run the PHP code which is written in the textarea.

BUT, I really like to apply code highlighter to my text box. With this regard, I have tried a couple of ways:

1. I have tried "highlight.js" --> https://highlightjs.org/
2. I have tried "codemirror"  --> https://codemirror.net/

Not only I can't get my PHP code to be highlighted, but also it can't be running anymore.

*I need to mention that the same method is working fine to highlight XML code, but it won't run too!*

As far as I understood, when we apply these code highlighters, the textarea will not act like a textarea anymore. So, is there anyway that I can highlight my PHP code and then run it?

Comment: Textarea can contain only plain text. You need to use `div` or `section` with an attribute `contenteditable`

Comment: @MysterX thanks for your comment. can you please answer my question with a simple example that I can get the idea? Furthermore, I will appreciate, if you can explain why the XML code can be highlighted while the PHP can't?

Comment: Nope man, sorry, it is a huge amount of work, I have no readymade examples, so you need to research and implement this solution by yourself

Comment: @MysterX as I have mentioned in the question, it can not be running when it turns to be or act like a div!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to encounter with this issue is to make an middle DIV called `modifyCodeDiv`:

```
<div id="modifyCodeDiv" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

`modifyCodeDiv` is getting the value of `modifyCode` textarea:

```
document.getElementById("modifyCodeDiv").innerHTML =
document.getElementById("modifyCode").value;
```

So, users can modify the code in the div `modifyCodeDiv`.

To execute the code, you need to send the value of `modifyCodeDiv` to `modifyCode`. As div does not have value attribute, you need to do:

```
var my_element = document.getElementById('modifyCodeDiv');      
var my_str = my_element.innerText || my_element.textContent; 

document.getElementById("modifyCode").value = my_str;
```

Furthermore, you can apply highlight.js to your div `modifyCodeDiv`.